# Как заставить мяч вращаться и зациклить анимацию

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

*Это рабочая(суперкривая и тупая) анимашка, и чтобы её "дополнительно оживить" надо бы заставить шар вращаться (как колесо, и чтоб скорость вращения мяча была примерно равна скорости мяча), и чтобы, доехав до конца маршрута, он телепортировался в начало и опять повторял движение. И, есть ли какой-нибудь способ удлинить дорогу на 20px? И ещё, если можно, добавить кнопочку, останавливающую всю анимацию.*

```js
train.onclick = function() {
    let start = Date.now();
    var inputs = document.getElementById('numbers')
    var inputt = document.getElementById('numbert')

    var numbers = Number(inputs.value);
    var numbert = Number(inputt.value);

    var sum = 0; 
    let delta = 20*numbers/(numbert*500); 
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
      let timePassed = Date.now() - start;
      train.style.left = sum + 'px';
      sum += delta;    
      if (sum > numbers) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 20);
    }
```

```css
#train {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50px 50px,  red, black);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes train {
    0%{bottom: 0%;}
    50%{transform: rotate(360deg);}  
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}

#road {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="road"></div>
  
    
  <h3>Время</h3>
  <input type='number' id='numbert' value="2">


  
  <h3>Расстояние</h3>
  <input type='number' id='numbers' value="300" oninput="road.style.width = `${this.value}px`;">
```

Comment: Вопрос в чем? есть ли возможность - есть, сделать это за вас - я пас, подсказать что то - уточните что именно =)

Comment: Да тут вроде добавить пару строчек, на все вопросы, кроме вращения шара. А этот куда сложнее, и как это сделать я не представляю

Comment: Да тут вся задача на пару строчек кода простите, дело то в том что этот код вы не писали сами? этот сайт не про "дайте готовое", а про "помогите научится" :) а решать школьные задачки те кто здесь помогают - научились давно :)

Comment: Этот код я на 80% писал сам, остальное списывал отсюда или туториалов. Я столько часов убил на эту и ещё пару других....Если хотите, зайдите в мой профиль и найдите там кучу вопросов по ним

Comment: Ну т.е. вы понимаете что делает каждая строчка этого кода? Т.е. вы знаете где задавали длину дороги? что мешает вам изменить это значение?)

Comment: Ну так вот, <input type='number' id='numbers' value="300" oninput="road.style.width = `${this.value}px`;"> в этой строчке, но если я добавляю в фрагмент({this.value}px) +20px или *0.2, то эта строчка перестаёт работать (не передаёт значение в css, не изменяя длину объекта).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135685/discussion-between---and--).